# Is there a R function to sort dataframe based on closest given value?

Tags: r, sorting

Is there a R function to sort dataframe based on closest given value?

for example: `x<-c(5,4,9,6,1,4,2,7)`

given `value = 4`

expected output: `(4,4,5,6,2,7,1,9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R option (but I believe [@MrFlick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68708029/12158757) is more concise)

```
> as.numeric(names(sort(abs(setNames(x, x) - 4))))
[1] 4 4 5 6 2 1 7 9
```

Answer (score 4):

You can order by the difference between `x` and 4

```
x <- c(5,4,9,6,1,4,2,7)
x[ order(abs(x-4)) ]
# [1] 4 4 5 6 2 1 7 9
```